# How to make an object (triangle) transparent inside leaving angles highlighted?

Tags: texturing, objects

I am new to Blender but have done a couple of tutorials already. Now I wonder how can I select the angles of a triangle and fill the content of a triangle with black. Or maybe there is an option to clear this content and leave it fully transparent? I have attached a screenshot to get a better understanding of what I want. Thanks in Advance! :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a wireframe material, incorporating a holdout shader:

[image]

The holdout shader is like transparency emission-- it writes transparency to the render.  It sounds like that's what you want, but there are other nodes you can mix in: transparent BSDF or black emission.

The wireframe node tells you how close to an edge you are.  Notice that the single visible quad is crossed by the wireframe: wireframe is evaluated after triangulation of the mesh.  You mentioned triangles, so I'm not sure this is a concern for you.  If it is, this could be addressed most easily by simply deleting the quad face, or reassigning it to a straight holdout, transparent, or emissive material.  (Or in a number of other ways.)

A different way to achieve what you want is to use a wireframe modifier.  Rather than affecting how the face is drawn, a wireframe modifier turns your edges into tubes:

[image]

On this particular version, I'm using a wireframe modifier with "replace original" unchecked, with a material offset.  The base shape gets the holdout material, while a wireframe mesh is created on top of it with a black emission material.

Either of these might be better than the other, depending on details of your specific project.

Answer (score 3):

You could mark the edges as [Freestyle](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/index.html?highlight=freestyle). You have options: in EEVEE, you can render the layer on its own, by unchecking all other passes in the View Layer Properties tab, or in Cycles, as illustrated here, you can check 'As Render Pass'.

In this example, 'Film' is set to 'Transparent' in the Rendering tab, and the Freestlyle layer is laid over an *Input>RGB* node  black in the compositor.

[image]

(Blender 2.92)