# How do I render like this picture?

Tags: modeling, rendering

[image]

I'd like to render flat and wireframe like this.
How do I control render setting?

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos This is quite a simple question on how to create a certain shader and I've almost finished my answer.

Comment: The keywords are 'wireframe' and 'shader'. You already have the 'wireframe' in the description but not in the title. If you search for it you will find several similar questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/36701/107598 - https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23616/107598 - https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/51802/107598 - https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/221321/107598 - https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/132556/107598

Answer (score 3):

A relatively easy way is when you have a quite low-poly mesh with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier on it to smooth it out. And the faces of the object should be quads. I call it an easy way, but I'll take the time to explain it in detail.

At first, I'm using a simple plane to show the basic shader setup for a single quad face. A plane has a square face that by default completely fills the UV map. The UV map is 2-dimensional and goes from bottom left X, Y = (0, 0) to top right with X, Y = (1, 1), so in X it has a range of 0 to 1 and the same for Y.

Which means, if you take a *Texture Coordinate* node and then plug the *UV* output into a *Separate XYZ* node, the X values are a black to white gradient from left to right, and the Y values a black to white gradient from bottom to top, here showing the X values:

[image: UV coordinates]

If you now plug the X values into a *Math* node set to *Compare*, leave the second value at 0.5 and the *Epsilon* (the tolerance in this case) to something between 0 and 0.5, you will get "true" (=1) for all values in the range of 0.5 - *Epsilon* to 0.5 + *Epsilon* and false (=0) outside this range. Here is an example with *Epsilon* = 0.45, the plane is now showing black borders to the left and right where the result is false, from 0 to 0.05 and 0.95 to 1. The rest is white:

[image: compare to 0.5]

When you do the same with the Y values, you get black borders on the bottom and top of the plane. Now you can combine both with a *Math* node set to either *Minimum* or *Multiply* (the result is the same) and you get a black border around the square (I also use a *Value* node for *Epsilon* to be able to adjust them both simultaneously):

[image: combining x and y]

If you use this as a mix factor for a *Mix Color* node, the black area will show the first color and the white area the second color. I'm using some kind of greenish and a dark grey and you probably already get an idea where this is going:

[image: color mix]

This is basically the material, to get some shading on it you just need to plug this color output into the *Base Color* of a *Principled BSDF* node, but I'll get to the rest later. The more important is now how to get this on any arbitrary model.

I'll take Suzanne as example. The mesh is mostly quads with some triangles, which is not ideal but sometimes it does not really show, depending on the actual mesh. If you go into *Edit Mode* you can see, Suzanne comes like most mesh primitives in Blender with a ready-to-use UV layout:

[image: uv layout monkey]

But this is not needed. Instead, select all faces with <kbd>A</kbd>, then you can either press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Reset* in the *3D Viewport* or in the *UV Editor* menu choose *UV* > *Reset*. What this does is placing all faces individually on the UV map, each face normalized and using the complete map. Sounds complicated, but for each quad face this simply means, no matter what dimensions they have in the object, their UVs will be a regular 1×1 square. In the UV map they now all lie on top of each other (the diagonal lines come from the few triangles):

[image: reset uvs]

So when you now put the basic material created before on Suzanne, each face will become dark grey with a greenish border. It is not perfect though, because extreme size differences between the faces in the mesh will lead to varying line thicknesses, this method works best with meshes that have a mostly uniform resolution:

[image: monkey with uv grid material]

And adding a *Subdivision Surface* modifier now on the object smoothes out the low-poly edges of the base mesh (I've adjusted the *Epsilon* values to make the lines a bit thinner). Then I plug the color into *Principled BSDF* with a high *Roughness* value for the shading:

[image: subdivided and shaded]

And this is it. For the background you can use a subdivided plane also with reset UVs and it is finished. You can also use this border separation for other settings like roughness, emission, metallic, bump if you want to make a slightly different material then the reference.